# Is it ok to include a lot of columns in a nonclustered index on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

Given following example:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Address_PostalCode  
ON Person.Address (PostalCode)  
INCLUDE (AddressLine1);  
GO
```

If I included more columns in the INCLUDE list like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Address_PostalCode  
ON Person.Address (PostalCode)  
INCLUDE (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, StateProvinceID, Latitude, Longitute, Zip, Country, etc... );  
GO
```

Does this require more space on disk?

Or put differently: is data that is covered in the `INCLUDE` list duplicated on the leaf nodes of the index?

Comment: Everything in a nonclustered index is duplicated data, either in the key or in the included columns. Such an index will have a very big overhead.

Comment: Yes.  You can probably find a deeper answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791413/indexes-with-included-columns-whats-the-difference

Comment: At the extreme end of the scale, including every column in the index would effectively mean you're storing the table twice, with the rows in different order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

And that is precisely the reason of the include: Sacrifice some space but make (some) queries not having to do a key lookup when they need the included columns, but take them from the index itself.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you're not merely sacrificing space, but also spending more I/O on modifications. Whether the tradeoffs are worth it depends, of course.